# Configuring iptables rules for HAProxy and others

Tags: iptables, haproxy

I have the following relevant settings for `HAProxy`:

```
defaults
    log             global
    mode            http
    option          httplog
    option          dontlognull
    retries         3
    option          redispatch
    maxconn         500
    contimeout      5s
    clitimeout      15s
    srvtimeout      15s

frontend public
    bind    *:80
    option  http-server-close
    option  http-pretend-keepalive
    option  forwardfor
    # ACLs
    ...
```

I have three backends (including a `Nginx` server) configured in `HAProxy`, all listening on different ports of `127.0.0.1`. And my `iptables` config is this:

```
*filter

#  Allows all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

#  Accepts all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#  Allows all outbound traffic
#  You can modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

#  Allows HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites)
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

#  Allows SSH connections
#
#  THE -dport NUMBER IS THE SAME ONE YOU SET UP IN THE SSHD_CONFIG FILE
#
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

#  Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

#  log iptables denied calls
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

#  Reject all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

My questions are:

1. Would the above `iptables` config work with the settings/options in my `HAProxy` config?
2. I am also runnning a `postgres` and a `redis` server on the same machine, what settings do I need to adjust for these two to enable them work with `iptables`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, they are operating at different OSI layers.
2. None, you're already allowing local host connections.